# (C++11) Variadic template sequence printing

Tags: c++, c++11, sequence, variadic-templates

I was given a template meta-programming challenge of using only C++11 standard to print out a series of integers in powers of 2 which I have successfully done:

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t... Ns>
struct index_sequence
{
    static void print()
    {
        const size_t numbers[] = {Ns...};
        for (const auto& number : numbers)
        {
            std::cout << number << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

//#include <cmath>

template <size_t Counter, size_t... Rest>
struct make_sequence_impl
{
    using type = typename make_sequence_impl<
        Counter - 1,
        static_cast<size_t>(1) << Counter, Rest...>::type;
};

template <size_t... Rest>
struct make_sequence_impl<0, Rest...>
{
    using type = index_sequence<static_cast<size_t>(1) << 0, Rest...>;
};

template <size_t T>
using make_sequence = typename make_sequence_impl<T>::type;

int main()
{
    make_sequence<N>::print();
}
```

Assuming N is 5, it would print 1, 2, 4, 8, 16.

However, I was subsequently challenged to do the same thing, except that this time I have to print them in reverse order (i.e. 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 for N = 5). I am totally stumped but I am very sure it involved only a slight change to the code which I can't figure out how.

Any help would be appreciated. Got into template meta-programming a few days ago.

Comment: use `reverse_iterator` in the loop?

Comment: I would mimic `std::make_integer_sequence` to have `sequence<Is...>`, then have transform method to have `sequence<(1 << Is)...>` or `sequence<(1 << (sizeof...(Is) - 1 -Is))...>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is the minimal change, but instead of *"push_front"* the sequence, you might *"push_back"*.

```
template <size_t Counter, size_t... Rest>
struct make_sequence_impl
{
    using type = typename make_sequence_impl<
        Counter - 1,
        Rest...,
        static_cast<size_t>(1) << Counter>::type;
};

template <size_t... Rest>
struct make_sequence_impl<0, Rest...>
{
    using type = index_sequence<Rest..., static_cast<size_t>(1) << 0>;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a662737dd74f1c5)

On my side, I would mimic `std::make_index_sequence` to have `0, 1, 2, .., N-1` and then use it directly:

```
emplate <size_t Counter, size_t... Rest>
struct make_sequence_impl
{
    using type = typename make_sequence_impl<
        Counter - 1,
        Counter,
        Rest...>::type;
};

template <size_t... Rest>
struct make_sequence_impl<0, Rest...>
{
    using type = index_sequence<0, Rest...>;
};
```

and then

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
void print( index_sequence<Is...> )
{
    for (const auto& number : {Is...})
    {
        std::cout << number << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


template <std::size_t ... Is>
void print_pow2( index_sequence<Is...> )
{
    print(index_sequence<(1u << Is)...>{});
}

template <std::size_t ... Is>
void print_pow2_inv( index_sequence<Is...> )
{
    print(index_sequence<(1u << (sizeof...(Is) - 1 - Is))...>{});
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5092bc7dba6a0a41)

Comment: Oh my god... why did I never think of that? I always thought that you cant "push_front" a templated parameter pack sequence and I was nearing the point of exploring implementation of a function to reverse-unpack. Thank you so much! I wished I could be better at this...

Comment: Another question about your "push_front" implementation and the "minic make_index_sequence" implementation. I have tried both and they both behaved as intended. Are there any practical differences between the two or is the latter just an implementation that you would have done?

Comment: probably a naming issue first, as your `make_sequence` doesn't match `std::make_sequence`, `make_sequnce_pow` would have been better naming. then once a sequnce is done, easier to manipulate it that recreate another one each time we require it.